# Como usar mi propia librería de facelets en scope provided en un proyecto maven

Tags: jsf, maven, ejb

Estoy trabajando en un un proyecto JEE, la idea es conectar multiples aplicaciones mediante SOA y SSO, estas aplicaciones tendrán imagenes css js y templates comunes, por esta razón incluí todos los componentes comunes en un jar como se explica en este post [Packaging facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/packaging-facelets-files-templates-includes-composites-in-a-jar)

Ahora bien, cuando uso mi nuevo jar en cualquiera de mis proyectos maven, este funciona bien, siempre y cuando lo utilice con scope runtime o compile, pero mi objetivo es usarlo con scope **provided**, de este modo tendré unicamente un artefacto desplegado para que sea usado por los demas aplicativos.

Sin embargo si uso scope provided tengo RESOURCE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION

Tuve tambien la idea de usarlo como **deployed.artefacto.jar** pero en este caso arroja error al usar los controllers de dicho artefacto

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes el RESOURCE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION? ¿Has incluido tu librería en el servidor de aplicaciones?

Comment: Cuando intento llamar a cualquier pagina jsf que use uno de los componentes comunes, he intentado usarlo como 

`<Dependencies>deployment.portalejb.jar</Dependencies>`

SIn embargo el error se mantiene, debería usarlo como jboss module..?